# Prove that $|x+y+z| \le |x|+|y| +| z|$ for all $x, y, z$

Tags: inequality

> Prove that $$\lvert x+y+z \rvert \le \lvert x \rvert  + \lvert y \rvert + \lvert z\rvert $$ for all $x, y, z$.

Comment: Hint: $x+y+z=(x+y)+z$

Comment: @Subhadeep Please don't use `\mid` when you mean absolute value. The spacing is all wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We have 
$|A|+|B| \geqslant |A+B|$ for all reals $A,B$ 

so
$$|x|+|y|+|z| \geqslant |x+y|+|z| \geqslant |x+y+z|$$ 
as desried.

Answer (score 1):

You can prove it by using triangle inequality of two numbers.Consider $(y+z)$ as a single entity,$|x+(y+z)|\le |x|+|y+z| $, now use triangle inequality on $|y+z|$, and you will get your answer.